# ASP NET - Como crear una carpeta particular por cada Usuario y permitir el acceso solo al propietario

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

Tengo una aplicación web ASP .NET. Y necesito crear una carpeta por usuario y habilitar el acceso solo al usuario propietario. Es porque tengo un módulo en la aplicación que puede cargar archivos como "G-Dirve". ¿Como lo puedo hacer? sucede que no tengo idea de por dónde empezar.
¡Ayuda! ¡Gracias!

PD: Uso Membership autentication.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!